# Can send header even though I have output

Tags: php

Should'nt the following give an error message? It sends me to `domain.com/asdad/` instead of giving me an error message.

```
<?php
echo 'asdadasdasd';
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/newtest.php') {
    header("Location: /asdad/");
    exit;
}
?>
```

I view this directly, no other files or code before or after this. Should'nt `header` give me an error and NOT send me to the new page as I have output before the `header`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `phpinfo()`, you probably have `output_buffering` switched on.

Comment: `output_buffering` was set to 4096, setting it to Off fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

PHP output, like most IO, is often put into a temporary buffer until a critical amount is reached (or a user calls `flush`), at which point the contents are flushed to the browser. If you manage to send a `header` before the output buffer is flushed, you can get away with it.

However, this is not something you rely on, as the buffer size (or, indeed, buffering at all) can vary between installations.